# Query creating through method name,using two tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So a schedule belongs to a certain user,and can be active for multiple dates or none.I am trying to use a query created via method name where it finds the schedule where userId="x" AND the dateActiveScheduleItem date is="x".My repo for the schedule is below but the error I got is "No property dateActiveScheduleItemDate found for type Schedule!"

```
  @Repository
  public interface ScheduleDao extends JpaRepository<Schedule,Long> {
  Schedule findByUserIdAndDateActiveScheduleItemDate(Long 
 userId,java.util.Date date);
 }
```

Schedule(the list of dateActiveScheduleItems is the link to the 2nd table)

```
@Entity
public class Schedule {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "usergroup_id")
private UserGroup userGroup;

private String description;


private boolean master;//is this a schedule for all supervalus(true) or one supervalu(false)

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<DateActiveScheduleItem> dateActiveScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<MusicScheduleItem> musicScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public UserGroup getUserGroup() {
    return userGroup;
}

public void setUserGroup(UserGroup userGroup) {
    this.userGroup = userGroup;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}


public boolean isMaster() {
    return master;
}

public void setMaster(boolean master) {
    this.master = master;
}

public List<DateActiveScheduleItem> getDateActiveScheduleItems() {
    return dateActiveScheduleItems;
}

public void setDateActiveScheduleItems(List<DateActiveScheduleItem> dateActiveScheduleItems) {
    this.dateActiveScheduleItems = dateActiveScheduleItems;
}

public List<MusicScheduleItem> getMusicScheduleItems() {
    return musicScheduleItems;
}

public void setMusicScheduleItems(List<MusicScheduleItem> musicScheduleItems) {
    this.musicScheduleItems = musicScheduleItems;
}
}
```

DateActiveScheduleItem.java

```
 @Entity
 public class DateActiveScheduleItem {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date date;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id")
private Schedule schedule;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method name should be

```
 findByUserIdAndDateActiveScheduleItems_Date
```

So It will be like this

```
@Repository
  public interface ScheduleDao extends JpaRepository<Schedule,Long> {
  Schedule findByUserIdAndDateActiveScheduleItems_Date(Long 
 userId,java.util.Date date);
 }
```

Because your variable name is dateActiveScheduleItems and inside that you have date. So you should use `_`